# link_to triggering method on object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `link_to` line of code in an `html.erb` file:

```
<%= link_to "no thanks" %>
```

I want clicking this link to trigger the `:reject` state method I have set in this 'treating.rb' model file:

```
class Treating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :intro, :proposed_date, :proposed_location, :requestee_id, :state

  state_machine :state, :initial => :pending do

    event :reject do
        transition [:pending] => :rejected
    end

    event :reply do
        transition [:pending, :rejected] => :replied
    end

    event :archive do
      transition [:rejected] => :archived
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

What do I put in my `link_to` line of code to get the 'treating' it is referring to to have its status changed from 'pending' to 'rejected'? I've tried `action =>` and `method =>` with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a controller action to perform this, for example:

```
# ?.html.erb
<%= link_to "no thanks", reject_treating_path(@treating), method: :post %>

# config/routes.rb
resources :treatings do
  member do
    post :reject
  end
end

# app/controllers/treatings.rb
class TreatingsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /treatings/:id/reject
  def reject
    current_user.treatings.find(params[:id]).reject!
    redirect_to treatings_path, notice: "Treating was rejected"
  end
end
```

I've added a member action for the treating resource, and assumed that treatings belong to a user.

Comment: thank you, but i now get a route error: No route matches {:action=>"reject", :controller=>"treatings"}. also, treatings belong to users as aliases (received_treatings and sent_treatings). hope this helps

Comment: figured it out: the '@treating' instance var in my html.erb needed to be 'treating' instead. thanks!